# Find spring stiffness of a frame structure

Tags: classical-mechanics, material-science, spring, elasticity

I would like to calculate the spring constant of a frame structure.
I thought that I could do it like this:

1. I apply a point force on the structure:
   [image]
2. Then I calculate the displacement at that same point:
   [image]

Finnaly, I asume that the material bends within its elastic limit:
$k=\frac{F}{\delta_y}$

**Question1: Do you agree with this method?**

**Question2: If I have a different type of loading, for instance a distributed load, would the spring constant change?**